# Track changes in client and send to server

Tags: ef-code-first, wcf-data-services, azure-worker-roles, n-tier-architecture, change-tracking

I am planning a 3-tiered architecture in which I need to track changes to domain objects on the client (a Windows Store app) then send those changes back to the server (an Azure worker-role).  I just found out about WCF Data Services which I can run on the client and integrate with Entity Framework Code First on the server.  It looks okay but I'm wondering what other tools may also be available.

Are there any alternatives to WCF Data Services for tracking changes in client then sending them to server?  If available, I'd like a solution that doesn't require generated DTO classes but instead sends the deltas alone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using rest services?
Im not an AZURE user, but use elsewhere.
[Azure rest services docu](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/rest-service-using-web-api/)

Comment: please add comment for downvote. The question was Are there any alternatives to WCF Data Services?. Why is a REST service not a valid option.Or are you objecting to my lack of AZURE experience?

Comment: Use a REST service how?  Seems similar to answering any SO question with "use your computer".

Comment: The analogy you use is misplaced. You asked `Are there any alternatives to WCF Data Services?` which i think i can fairly see as ODATA services   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx   So yes a very useful alternative is REST services . The link is AZURE rest service info. Since you added you need in AZURE.    might not be enough info for you. Sorry but your response seems unfair to me

Comment: The change tracking feature of WCF Data Services is *not* ODATA.  In any case, ODATA *is* RESTful already.

Comment: Ok wasnt aware there was a specific change tracker in WCF Data Services. I was thinking about the generic concept. Sorry to have wasted your time.   But still think the ODATA versus REST is valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458407/difference-between-odata-and-rest-web-services